# GitHub actions "extend" existing job

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to have some github actions workflow, which should check linting, check if building the code is successful, and if so run tests.

My first "job" is to install the dependencies. Every job needs that done, so I do the following in every job:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Cache functions node_modules
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: node_modules
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('package.json') }}

- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm ci
```

Is there a way to define this as job `dependencies`, and then have another job, `lint` extending this job? There's a cache, so it won't re-install, but it feels like long code repetition for no reason.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE** Initially it was not possible to us uses in composite actions it is possible now for some time. For more details please check [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/)

If you want to apply DRY rule here you should check [composite run steps](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-08-07-github-actions-composite-run-steps/)

> You can now create reusable actions using shell scripts and even mix multiple shell languages in the same action. You probably have a lot of shell script to automate many tasks, now you can easily turn them into an action and reuse them for different workflows.

You can use it as follow:

main file:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: octocat/say-hello@v1
      with: 
        os: ${{ runner.os }}
```

`octocat/say-hello/action.yml`:

```yaml
inputs:
  name: 
    os: 'Your os'
    default: 'No os default'
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps: 
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Cache functions node_modules
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: node_modules
        key: ${{ inputs.os }}-${{ hashFiles('package.json') }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
```

ANd you if plan to keep composite in the same repo as main workflow then refer to it as

```
    - uses: ./.github/actions/say-hello
```

for this folder structure:

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it seems like using `uses` inside a composite is not allowed. See https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/862

Comment: @Amit not it is possible https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/